# Rendering only published taxonomy

Tags: drupal, taxonomy-terms

It's rendering taxonmy terms. I need only published terms. There are two languages in site. Publish status can be translated. I need help with condition. I don't work with php. Could anyone help?

```
foreach ($child_terms as $term) {
    $taxonomy_term = \Drupal\taxonomy\Entity\Term::load($term->tid);
    $taxonomy_term_trans = \Drupal::service('entity.repository')->getTranslationFromContext($taxonomy_term, $curr_langcode);
    if (????) {
        $child_term_options[$term->tid] = $taxonomy_term_trans->getName();
      }
    }
```

Comment: Didn't use it before, but try what will  "$taxonomy_term_trans->status()" give you.
So "if ($taxonomy_term_trans->status())" ...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you pretend to loop terms that are children of some given term.
Assuming you know the term id of the parent term.

```
<?php

$status = TRUE;
$lang_code = \Drupal::languageManager()
                    ->getCurrentLanguage()
                    ->getId();

$child_terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
                    ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
                    ->loadByProperties([
                        'parent' => $parent_tid,
                        'status' => $status,
                        'langcode' => $lang_code,
                    ]);

foreach ($child_terms as $term) {

    $name = $term->getName();
    $tid = $term->id();

}
```

Comment: This looks good. But this line in foreach $child_term_options[$term->tid] = $term->getName(); give me NoInterfaceProperties: Interfaces cannot have properties. How can I get id and name?

Comment: Check edited answer.